Challenge in SQL JSON_VALUE to Query XDB.Shards: Assistance for the xdb_Collection.Intreactions.Events Column
I am currently endeavouring to query XDB.Shards in order to generate a custom analytics report tailored to meet the specific requirements of our clients.
My attempts to utilize JSON_VALUE for querying on the xdb_collection.ContactFacets have been successful, allowing me to filter data from the FacetData column.
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_VALUE( FacetData, '$.Title')
  FROM [xdb_collection].[ContactFacets]
  Where FacetKey = 'XXXXXX'

However, encountering a challenge as JSON_VALUE is not functioning as expected on the xdb_Collection.Intreactions Events column.
SELECT DISTINCT  JSON_VALUE( Events, '$.Title') AS TITLE  FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions]


I have also tried
SELECT TOP 10 
  interaction.InteractionId,
  JSON_VALUE(interaction.Events, '$[0].Title' ) as Title
FROM 
  [xdb_collection].[Interactions] interaction


Any assistance on how to effectively query the JSON in the Events column would be greatly appreciated.

I will request you to explore PowerBI to create custom reports. You can ingest xDB data into PowerbI

After looking at the data in the database, it became evident that the Events value was not in JSON format due to the presence of extra square brackets at the start and end. To resolve this issue, I added a trim function to the square brackets after three days, which allowed me to extract the data successfully.
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
        interaction.InteractionId
      , JSON_VALUE(TRIM('[]'  FROM [Events]) , '$.Url') as Title
  FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions] interaction

Given below is the screen short
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Intentionally changed to conceal other project-specific details and display only the "Item Not founds.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/vaRmWpo7.png

Since you trying to fetch distinct title from the Events Property inside the Interactions table and Events property being an array of events in xConnect, you can use following query to achieve the desired result with Cross Apply function as below.
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
    SELECT Distinct(JSON_VALUE(ValueData.value, '$.Url')) as Url
    FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions] as Interaction
    Cross Apply OPENJSON(Interaction.Events) As ValueData
) sub
Where sub.Url is not null

This will return you all the distinct urls traversed on the website as below. Similarly you can use the same query for fetching other properties as well.

Hope this helps!!!

Thanks for your answer. But I am trying to find URL for each interaction. This can be a nested query for my purpose but it will degrade the performance as I have 10Millions of record to get data from. But based on your Query I got a Click of Idea and it worked. Thanks once again.

@SunilRana I just checked the query you uploaded only returns distinct result from the first object in the array. It does not read objects starting from index 2. In case this satisifies the requirement, it should be good..But since you are creating reports I believe you should read all the events.

Events columns contains JSON which is an array.
That's why  you need to add [0] to get the first event and only then Title, e.g.:
SELECT TOP 10 
  interaction.InteractionId,
  JSON_VALUE(interaction.Events, '$[0].Url' ) as Url,
  JSON_VALUE(interaction.Events, '$[0].Title' ) as Title
FROM 
  [xdb_collection].[Interactions] interaction


Events columns contains JSON which is an array.
You need to add [0] to get the event.
In your case please find the example
SELECT COALESCE(JSON_VALUE(i.Events, '$[0].DefinitionId'), 'Unknown') AS definition_id
FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions] i
Where ContactId = 'C5095C39-66C8-0000-0000-06C7C7FA1491';

Here I have checked with a ContactId and the value field of DefinitionId
Please check and let me know.
Hope this helps !!!
